# Hiking / nature walking in Cannes area without a car?

Tags: public-transport, hiking, cannes

I am visiting several European destinations this summer, and I prefer spending some time in the nature. I've been to Cannes before and know the hills/mountains south west of Cannes is great! However, when I've been there before, I had access to a car to drive into the center of the mountains.

**What I am looking for:**

Some nice hiking trips near Cannes (less than 20km). It's important you can get there without a car, **so bus / train is preferable**.

My backup plan is getting to Theoule-sur-Mer, and then walk to some other city close by through the mountains. So an answer describing HOW to get to Theoule-sur-mer and home again by public transport also counts as an answer ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Esterel

As you mentioned, the Esterel hills are very nice and a very good spot for hiking and mountain biking. To go there, you can take the regional train from Cannes. [The TER](http://www.voyages-sncf.com) to Les Arcs-Draguignan stops in Théoule-sur-Mer or the following stops. The seaside between Théoule-sur-Mer and Anthéor is gorgeous, but this is better with a road bike (it would be dangerous to walk along the road). From Théoule, there is for example the *Circuit des Monges*, No. 21 in the [mountain biking Randoxygène guidebook](http://asp.zone-secure.net/v2/index.jsp?id=105/99/12833) which is actually better fitted for hiking. There are a lot of other hikes in the area, a simple search on a website like [gpsies](http://www.gpsies.com/home.do?language=en#14_43.492097869284_6.923489570617676_mapQuest) gives some ideas. You can easily find half-day or full-day hikes.

### Sophia

As @Midhat suggested, you can take [the bus 630](http://www.cg06.fr/document/?f=servir-les-habitants/fr/630.pdf) to Sophia/Valbonne area from which you can do some short hikes.

### Auron/Isola

I know this is way further, but you can go up to Isola or Auron via Nice. You can take a train at 6am to Nice, and then the *Rando-bus* (buses [730](http://www.cg06.fr/document/?f=servir-les-habitants/fr/730.pdf) or [740](http://www.cg06.fr/document/?f=servir-les-habitants/fr/740.pdf) or [750](http://www.cg06.fr/document/?f=servir-les-habitants/fr/750.pdf)). There are hikes from up there.

### Vallée des Merveilles

A famous hike in Southern Alps is the [*Vallée des Merveilles*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vall%C3%A9e_des_Merveilles). There is a train departing from Nice (again you can take a Cannes-Nice and transfer) called [*Train des Merveilles*](http://telechargement.ter-sncf.com/Images/Paca/Tridion/EXE.Merveilles_GB_tcm-27-88671.pdf). It stops in some towns from which you can hike, sometimes [for a couple days](http://www.tendemerveilles.com/mercantour-merveilles/randonnees-promenades/la-vallee-des-merveilles.html).

### Train des Pignes

A last possibility is to take the *Train des Pignes*, again from Nice, offers [some hikes](http://telechargement.ter-sncf.com/Images/Paca/Tridion/EXE.Merveilles_GB_tcm-27-88671.pdf) from its stops.

### Practical information

On trains, you are allowed to take your bike. On buses, this is never possible. The price of trains depends on the distance and if you are under 26, you can have 25% off during off-peak hours. Buses cost 1 euro per trip, except the *Rando-bus* which costs 4 euros and should be [reserved beforehand](http://www.lignesdazur.com/reservation/?rub_code=148).

Comment: Wow, that's a really amazing answer. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 3):

There are a few forest trails around Antibes and Sophia-Antipolis (and also near Mougins). Antibes and Sophia are well connected to Cannes with regular buses (Lignes D'Azur #200 or probably #630 as well). This will be a helpful website for you to find hiking tracks: http://randoxygene.org/pge/cartographie/index.php?rubrique=2